# Python input type field doesn't display

Tags: python, input

complete Python noob here.

I was trying to use the input() function in Python but the field to which I'm supposed to type something didn't show after I hit enter. I tried to copy and paste but it still didn't work. Not sure what to do. Please help. :(

```
price = int(input('Please input desired price:'))
if price >= 3000 and price <= 10000:
    print ('Economy')
elif price >= 11000 and price <= 15000:
    print ('Mid')
elif price >= 16000 and price <= 20000:
    print ('High')
elif price >20000:
    print ('Luxury')
```

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: You must be using some IDE. Which? I prefer running my python scripts from a terminal or a Command Prompt.

Comment: We can't see your code for some reason.

Comment: Show us *how* you are using the `input()` function. You're asking us to imagine what you have written and tell you where the problem might be.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I'm using Anaconda.

Comment: @TheHappyBee and I edited the main post, sorry it's my first time posting a question here. Not really sure what I  was doing.

Comment: @BoarGules sorry, idk why the image I attached didn't show. I edited the main post though.

Comment: @kuykuy Anaconda? You mean Jupyter? That seems to be what your screenshot shows, which, btw, I just added back since it actually shows the problem.

Comment: I think the star means that that cell hasn't run yet or hasn't completed running. Is there a cell above it that's still running? Try checking the status of the kernel.

Comment: Thank you @wjandrea. Figured out why, the kernel was still busy.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly on my side:
[image]

Of course if you enter a price < 3000 it won‘t print anything because it doesn‘t meet any conditions of the statements below.

Also make sure to run your code from a file, if you copy paste it directly in IDLE it won‘t work, it‘s probably the same with anaconda :
[image]